# ObjectList Java task

Tags: java

I have been given the following main method and must write the code for the ObjectList class. I am supposed to infer the necessary functions of the ObjectList class and write the class myself, however I am unsure exactly what I need to do to fulfill this function. Any help understanding this is greatly appreciated. This is the code I was given:

```
   ObjectList ol = new ObjectList(3);

   String s = "Im Happy";
   Dog d = new Dog();
   DVD v = new DVD();
   Integer i = 1234;

   System.out.println(ol.add(s));
   System.out.println(ol.add(d));
   System.out.println(ol.add(v));
   System.out.println(ol.add(i));

   ol.remove(0);
   System.out.println(ol.add(i));


   System.out.println("Is the list full? "+ isFull()); 
   System.out.println("Is the list empty? "+ isEmpty());

   System.out.println("Total number of objects in the list: " + getTotal());

   Object g = ol.getObject(1);
   g.bark();
```

Comment: considering this code, since adding different types of objects to `ObjectList` it should be list data structure

Comment: From the fact that you are adding both a String and an Integer, their only common supertype is Object, so the add method must have the signature `public <Something> add (Object o)`; Because it appears in a println method without error, `<Something>` must be an Object of some type and not void. You can continue the analysis in similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple just need to create a list of `Object` types using `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` in the `ObjectList` class and implement the function as follows

```
public class ObjectList{
private ArrayList<Object> objects;
public ObjectList(int size)
{
    objects = new ArrayList<Object>(size);
}

public String add (Object object)
{
    objects.add(object);
    //anything you would like to return I'm just returning a string
    return "Object Added";
}

public void remove (int index)
{
    objects.remove(index);
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return objects.isEmpty();
}

public int getTotal()
{
    return objects.size();
}

public Object getObject(int index)
{
    return objects.get(index);
}
}
```

The `isFull()`is not needed since `ArrayList`size can change dynamically. You can use a simple array instead of `ArrayList` and then implement the `isFull()` function.

Also when getting an object using the get `getObject()` function, you need to cast it to the correct type before using there function. In your code `g.bark()` won't work because `Object` doesn't have a bark function

```
Object g = ol.getObject(1);

//This can give a runtime error if g is not a Dog
//Use try catch when casting
Dog d = (Dog)g;

d.bark();
```

**EDIT**

This is how you would implement `isFull()` and other functions if using arrays instead of `ArrayList` but for the sake of simplicity use the `ArrayList` version

```
 public class ObjectList{
 private Object[] objects;
 private int size = 0;
 private int currentIndex = 0;


public ObjectList(int size)
{
    this.size = size;
    objects = new Object[size];
}

 private boolean isFull() {
    if(currentIndex == size)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
 }

 public String add (java.lang.Object object)
{
    if ( ! isFull() ) {
        objects[currentIndex] = object;
        currentIndex++;
        return "Object added";
    }
    return "List full : object not added";

}

public void remove (int index)
{
    if( !isEmpty() ) {
        //shifting all the object to the left of deleted object 1 index to the left to fill the empty space
        for (int i = index; i < size - 1; i++) {
            objects[i] = objects[i + 1];
        }
        currentIndex--;
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if(currentIndex == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public int getTotal()
{
    return currentIndex;
}

public java.lang.Object getObject(int index)
{
    if(index < currentIndex)
     return objects[index];
    else
        return  null;
}
}
```

Comment: It’s true that it isn’t needed, but the OP asked for the isFull() method so you should add that to your answer

Comment: considering the OP just asked for a guideline but I almost showed the solution ,  I think its not that necessary to show and OP can try to do him/her self. But anyways I have added the array version in the post.

Answer (score 0):

What it seems you want to achieve is "expand" the functionality of an **ArrayList** and create a custom list of objects. What you could do is to create a class extending the ArrayList and define/override any other methods you want.

```
public class ObjectList extends ArrayList<Object> {
//constructor with initial capacity
private int length;
public ObjectList(int size){
   super(size);
   this.length= size;
}

public Object getObject(int index){
    return this.get(index);
}
}
```

Now you have the **add** and **remove** functions inherited from the ArrayList class and the **getObject** method.

Concerning the **isFull** method, you can check if the size of your ObjectList class is equal to the size it was instantiated with

```
if(this.size() == this.length){
return true
}
return false;
```

And **getTotal**

```
public int getTotal(){
return this.size();
}
```